# SVN SSL negotiation failed

Tags: ssl, openssl, svn

I am having issues using svn all of a sudden. When trying to update/commit or create a new checkout I get the following error. I cant seem to find much information about it.

svn: OPTIONS of 'https://username@svn.host.com/svn/repos/project/TRUNK': SSL negotiation failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856 (https://svn.host.com)

any idea?

Comment: What happens if you try loading that URL in a browser?  Do you get a more meaningful error message?  Also, is this a Subversion server that you control, or are you interacting with it strictly as a client?

Comment: I have no issues connecting through a browser. This is a server that we do control. Do you think this has to do with my openssl version .9.8l being higher than the servers openssl version .9.8e?

Comment: I tried upgrading to the latest openssl on the client side. Still same issue occurs.

Comment: Can you telnet to that address using port 443 and then issue a GET command?  Reason being is if you see readable text, you are sending unencrypted data through an SSL layer.  If you don't see readable text, ssl is working fine and we can continue to diagnose from there.

Comment: Just tested on my box, you can see readable text, but you should get an error like this: 
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.

Comment: Try to upgrade to latest OpenSSL on client side. There is some bug on OpenSSL that was fixed in OpenSSL 0.9.8m.

Comment: Does the error only happen on one/your computer? May be the server admin accidentially enabled HTTPS client auth - if then the client does not authenticate itself via a certificate the negotiation fails.

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of "openssl s_client -connect svn.host.com:443" from the client running svn?

Comment: Alternatively, get a network capture to see which phase of the handshake is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message when my Apache configuration was wrong - my *ServerName* parameter in `httpd.conf` did not match *hostname* in the self-signed certificate.