# SVN SSL Handshake Error

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, ssl, svn

I'm trying to access my own SVN server with the Cornerstone SVN client. I get the following error message:

> Description : Unable to contact the repository at
>   “https:/foo@bar.mooo.info:443” because an SSL session could not be
>   established.  Suggestion : This Mac was unable to present a valid
>   certificate or the server's certificate was rejected as invalid.
>   Technical Information
>
> ```
>   Error : V4SSLHandshakeFailureError \ 
>   Exception : ZSVNSSLHandshakeFailureException
> ```
>
> Causal Information
>
> Description : Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'https:/foo@bar.mooo.info/svn/robi'
>        Status : 175002
>
> Description : OPTIONS of 'https:/foo@bar.mooo.info/svn/robi': SSL
>   handshake failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856
>   (https:/bar.mooo.info)
>        Status : 175002

I think I found the solution by googling and using the search function. Described on [apache.org](http://subversion.apache.org/faq#ssl-error-336032856) or on serverfault ([SVN SSL negotiation failed](https://serverfault.com/questions/237395/svn-ssl-negotiation-failed)).

> This can happen when the hostname reported by the server does not the
>   match hostname given in the SSL certificate. Make sure your server
>   configuration uses correct values for ServerName and NameVirtualHost.

As embarrasing as it is, I can't implement it for two reasons.

A) I don't know where to edit the ServerName and NameVirtualHost (httpd.conf is not there in apache2 anymore)
B) I don't know which name I have to add there, the setup:
hostname: friedrich  (in the internal network)
DDNS name: bar.mooo.info (as entered in the SVN client)

OS: Debian GNU/Linux wheezy/sid (3.2.0-4-amd64)
Apache version: Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

more /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl.conf :

> [...]
>
> ```
>  <Location /svn>
>
>       DAV svn
>
>       SVNParentPath /srv/nas/hd0/svn
>
>       # this line must be added if you want SSL enabled
>
>       SSLRequireSSL
>
>  </Location>
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
>
>  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
> ```

Comment: I had to criple the links in the error description because i'm not allowed to post more than two :)

Comment: What OS is the SVN server running? What version of Apache?

Comment: OS: Debian GNU/Linux wheezy/sid (3.2.0-4-amd64)
Apache version: Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
(also added to question)

Comment: Have a look in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` for the SVN configuration.

Comment: attached it to the question

Comment: @rob Could the problem be that the URL specifies `https:/foo` instead of `https://foo`?

Comment: @ZaSter, It's not the case. He has no right to add URLs. Read, please, the first comment.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici, I did, but I did not understand what "criple the links" meant. Thanks.

Comment: @ZaSter It is a spam filter on ServerFault that rejects any URL from a user with very low reputation score.

Comment: See Apache Subversion FAQ at http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ssl-error-336032856

Comment: Your link was already in the quetion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to debug with:

```
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n"|openssl s_client -connect bar.mooo.info:443
```

If it is working, display the certificate with:

```
echo ""|openssl s_client -connect bar.mooo.info:443|openssl x509 -text -noout
```

Check that the `Subject:`  contains `CN=bar.mooo.info`
Check that the dates are correct and that the client time is in sync.
Check that the certificate is trusted by your client:

- Verify that the root certificate used to sign the host certificate is in the trust keystore
- Verify that root certificate is valid and not expired.

Comment: Fancy commands :D --> CN=friedrich. So I guess this is the problem

Comment: After a while, I know them by hart. :D And it was not my goal to remember them.

Comment: So do I have to generate a new self signed certificate or change the apache config? (or both)

Comment: Oke, added the FQDN (bar.mooo.info) as ServerName in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl.conf and it worked. Maybe you want to add it to your answer if anyone comes past this thread.

Comment: This depends on your particular apache setup. Took out of context it is not that useful, having that you did not post your entire apache configuration (Listen, NameVirtualHost, VirtualHost directives are missing in your configs you posted)